# Probability of a person correctly guessing at least one number out of the two number another person chooses

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

> Person A randomly chooses a number from 1 to 5 (inclusive) twice, so A ends up with 2 numbers chosen (can be the same number). Person B also makes a random choice from that list (only 1 number). What's the probability that B's choice match at least one of A's choices?

My interpretation of the question is: what's the probability that a randomly chosen number (call it $c$) between 1 and 5 is in the random set $[a, b],~ a $ and $b $are between 1 and 5.

My attempt of solving this question is the following:
There are 2 cases: 1.$ a$ and $b$ are different numbers; 2. $a$ and $b$ are the same.\

case 1:
if $a = b$, $\mathbb{P}[c \in \{a, b\}] = \mathbb{P}[c = a] = \frac{1}{5} $

case 2:
if $a \not= b$, $\mathbb{P}[c \in \{a, b\}] = \mathbb{P}[c = a] + \mathbb{P}[c = b]= \frac{2}{5} $

The probability of case 1 occurring is $\frac{1}{5}$. The calculation is similar to case 1. And the probability of case 2 occurring is $\frac{4}{5}$ since its the complement of case 1. Then, the answer is $$\mathbb{P}[\text{case 1}] \cdot\frac{1}{5} + \mathbb{P}[\text{case 2}]\cdot\frac{2}{5} = \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{5} + \frac{4}{5} \cdot\frac{2}{5} = \frac{3}{5}$$

However, the correct answer is $\frac{9}{25}$. This is confirmed by a simulation I ran.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think I got it. $\mathbb{P}[c\in \{a,b\}] = \mathbb{P}[c = a \lor c = b] =  \mathbb{P}[c = a] +  \mathbb{P}[c = b] -  \mathbb{P}[c = a \land c = b] = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{25} = \frac{9}{25}$
If you have anything else to add, please feel free to do so. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively $1-4/5*4/5$, the negation of the probability that $c\neq a$ and $c\neq b$.

Comment: Some nitpicking: **1** The term 'ramdomly choose' is a bit weird expression and it should be interpreted as drawing a random number. There is no choice involved. **2** Also the probabilities should be considered to be uniform (this is how 'randomly pick' is colloquially understood but formally it is incomplete). **3** In addition the draws need to be considered independent. (it states 'can be the same number' but is not so clear about the probability or potential correlation).

Comment: Your reasoning and calculations are all completely correct, except for the very last part. You correctly arrived at `P = 1/5 * 1/5 + 4/5 * 2/5`, but then you incorrectly simplified that to `P = 3/5` for some reason. But instead it simplifies to `P = 1/25 + 8/25 = 9/25`.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct up to the very last line:
$$\mathbb{P}[\text{case 1}] \cdot\frac{1}{5} + \mathbb{P}[\text{case 2}]\cdot\frac{2}{5} = \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{5} + \frac{4}{5} \cdot\frac{2}{5}$$

But this is not equal to $\frac{3}{5}$.

Instead:

$$\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{5} + \frac{4}{5} \cdot\frac{2}{5} = \frac{1 \cdot 1}{25} + \frac{4 \cdot 2}{25} = \frac{9}{25}$$

Comment: Ah I see, a very bad mistake I made...